# I tried to add multiple images using vue js html, but getting error as illegal invocation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

My html code is

```
<form method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="handleSubmit($event);">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group label-floating">
<label class="control-label">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="name" >
</div>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="row" v-for="(book, index) in phone" :key="index">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="book.mobile">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a @click="addNewRow">Add Another Phone</a>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="button success expand radius">
 <span id="save_image_titlebar_logo_live">Signature</span>
<label class="custom-file-upload">
 <input type="file" multiple ref="file_input" @change="uploadFiles">  
     <p>List of files</p>
     <ul>
       <li v-for="file in files">
         {{ file.name }}
       </li>
     </ul>
 </label>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Add

My vue js code is

```
addForm = new Vue({
el: "#addForm",
  data: {
        name: '',
         phone:[
          {
             mobile: null,

          },
        ],
        files: [],

  },
  methods: {
       addNewRow: function() {
          this.phone.push({ mobile: null, });
        },
        uploadFiles: function () {
      var files = this.$refs.file_input.files;

      var data = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0; i< files.length; i++) {
         data.append('input_name[]', files[i])
      }

      this.files = data.getAll('input_name[]')
      console.log(this.files);
    },
     handleSubmit: function(e) {
           var vm = this;
           data = {};
           data['name'] = this.name;
           data['phone'] = this.phone;
           data['photo'] = this.files;

            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://localhost:4000/s/',
              data: data,
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(e) {
              if (e.status)
              {
              vm.response = e;
              alert("success")

            }
              else {
                vm.response = e;
               console.log(vm.response);
               alert("Registration Failed") 
              }
          }
            });
            return false;
}, 
},
});
```

This is my vue js code

As soon as I click on submit button, I am getting error as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at File.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.r.param (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Vue$3.handleSubmit ((index):523)
    at Proxy.boundFn (vue.js:167)
```

I am a beginner to this area and doesnot have much idea. Can anybody please help me to solve this problem. It will be a great help.

I am really stuck on this work and can anybody please help me to sort out the problem. I tried several methods and not getting the result. Please help me

Comment: looks like a jquery error...

Comment: what sir? how can i correct

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you upload files using ajax.

The generally recommended way to do it is to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

I am able to get it to work without having `Illegal invocation` error in https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/p6yuzm26/12/ .

```
handleSubmit: function(e) {
  var vm = this;
  var form = $('#addForm form')[0];
  var data = new FormData(form);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:4000/s/',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    //dataType: 'json',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(e) {
       // ...
    }
  });
  return false;
},
```

This is the reference that I followed => https://coderwall.com/p/p-n7eq/file-uploads-with-jquery-html5-and-formdata .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sir, i tried this way, i am not able to pass anything.. is any data passing in your fiddle... i don;t think